# switching from a fragment to an activty and back to the fragment

Tags: android, android-activity

i created an activity that contains 5 fragments and one of the fragments contains a profile page and i created another activity to edit the profile page but when i click the save button to return to the Edit (fragment) . The app crashes..
i need help or suggestions

this is my Fragment code below :

```
public class MeFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.me, container, false);

    Button bt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btedit);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Editme.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

and this is the Editme Class:

```
Button btnLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btsave);
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            MeFragment save = new MeFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_content, save);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    };

    btnLoad.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: show us your stacktrace.

Comment: you trying to ask for the hosting FragmentManager of another activity or of the edit-activity. This wont work. Close activity first and then switch fragments.   Or Use an ActivityForResult in first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you opened another activity and after making some changes you'd like to go back to previous activity(with 5 fragments) simply call finish method instead of doing fragment transaction.

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
           finish();
        }
}
```

Comment: i would like to go back to the fragment i switched from , because i would have to pass data from that activity to the fragment.like image and two text views ..so maybe if you can give me a code that might work

Comment: you can always use instead of startActivity startActivityOnResult and then after going back to the 1st activity onActivityResult will be called where you can select appropriate fragment. But I'm not sure if using commit on fragment transaction is allowed during onActivityResult. So you may need to use commitAllowingStateLoss